# Import component/files from folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have this structure

```
-src
--modules
---Auth
----AuthContext
```

Inside my AuthContext

```
const AuthContext = createContext();
...AuthContext.

const useAuth = () => {
  ......
};

export {useAuth };
```

How I can import the useAuth like this

```
import { useAuth } from 'modules';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do a barrel export.

Basically create an `index.[js|ts]` file in the modules folder and export all from the other files within the index file using `export * form './abc'`

[here is more info](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel)

Comment: Yes, I know this approach but I have too many other folders to do index.js in each, I was looking at import-directory but not sure if its gonna work, trying it

Comment: pretty sure there is no way of doing that.